# On "How does the work of a pure mathematician impact society?"

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

The question [How does the work of a pure mathematician impact society?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137114/how-does-the-work-of-a-pure-mathematician-impact-society) was originally quickly closed, relatively quickly reopened, after a longer time closed again and has at the time of this edit a vote to reopen.

And, it also has many up-votes and answers.

There is not yet much meta discussion in the comments, yet in an effort to close the stable before the horse might bolt I thought I'd create this already, in case the need arises.

(This is a service-post; please do not interpret it as expressing an opinion for or against the question.)

Edited to reflect new situation and to correct initial oversight.

Comment: closed again, at about 15:21 California time, Friday, 19 July.

Comment: 15:18:17 to be precise; also UTC is the official time on MO ;-) Thanks for making me aware this had been closed/reopened already, this totally escaped me. // Btw, to whomever thought so, not sure it is already time to close this meta-question.

Comment: It's a duplicate of a thread on MSE, so yes it should be closed.  If people really think it's best on MO they should have migrated it.  But it does not appear to be a good question on either forum.

Comment: @Ryan: Without discussing the merits of the question, it feels to me that the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/can-i-use-my-powers-for-good (of which the question presently being discussed is supposed to be a duplicate) addresses a somewhat different, if related, point. It certainly asks for rather different advice than the question under discussion.

Comment: @Ricardo: It appears you missed this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447063/how-impact-the-work-of-a-pure-mathematician-in-the-society

Comment: To add to the comment by @RicardoAndrade (for people that did not click through to math.SE): the question under discussion was cross-posted on math.SE and on math.SE the post got (very quickly) closed as some (I assume 'abstract' or 'vague') duplicate of the question mentioned in the preceeding comment (which appears, but I do not really know, to be some catch all thing at almost 400 for 'what is math good for' type questions).

Comment: @RyanBudney: I am virtually certain that Ricardo Andrade had not "missed this", how else should he know the question which is the desiganted duplicate of that cross-post (the one linked in his comment). Rather his  point seems to be the cross post on math.SE *is closed* but as a dup of something there that is not really a dup, and I agreee (also without defending the question). But the argument for its closure here can hardly be that a crosspost on math.SE was closed as a dup of something rather than to migrate it here.

Comment: @quid: Thank you very much for your accurate clarifications of my comment above.